# Cookies not being sent by Fetch API

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, cookies, fetch-api

I have implemented a login system with Node.js which places a cookie in the client browser after a successful authentication. This cookie contains a username of client that is needed later for fetching client info from database, I'm trying to send that cookie to my Node server with Fetch API request and then read the username on the server-side, but this returns `undefined`. Here is my login system:

```
var cookie_parser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookie_parser('mysecretkey'));
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  var loginCredentials = {
    Email: req.body.email,
    Password: req.body.password,
  }
  loginCredentials.Password = hashPassword(loginCredentials.Password);
  console.log(loginCredentials);
  CheckPassword(loginCredentials, returnResult);
  // Function used by login API method to fetch password hash by email address from database
  function CheckPassword(loginCredentials, callback) {
    con.query("SELECT Password FROM Customers WHERE Email =?", loginCredentials.Email, function(err, result) {
      if (!err) {
        callback(false, result);
      } else {
        callback(true, err);
      }
    })
  }
  // Function for returning the login result
  // if login is successful, redirect user to front page
  function returnResult(error, result) {
    if (error) {
      res.send(`Database error: ${result}`);
    } else {
      if (result.length > 0 && loginCredentials.Password == result[0].Password) {
        res.cookie('user', loginCredentials.Email, {signed: true});
        res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/");
      } else {
        res.send("Login failed: incorrect email or password");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Then I'm trying to read username from that cookie:

```
app.get('/getCustomerInfo', function (req, res) {
  var username = req.signedCookies.user;
  console.log(username); // prints undefined
  if (username == undefined) {
    res.send('You are not logged in. Log in to place the order');
  } else {
    con.query("SELECT FirstName, LastName, Address, Email, Phone FROM Customers WHERE Email =?", username, function(err, result) {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(result);
        res.send(result);
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Here is my Fetch API request:

```
function GetCustomerInfo() {
  fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/getCustomerInfo`, {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include'
  })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        setCustomerInfo(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>
            {customerInfo}
          </h2>
        </div>
      );
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It seems you are not using the cookie parser. Can you add the app.js code here?

Comment: I'm importing it on server-side like: var cookie_parser = require('cookie-parser');

Comment: `credentials: "same-origin"`

Comment: Add the code in the question where you are adding this and other middleware.

Comment: Also you shouldn't use an email as an identifier for a cookie. It can be easily spoofed. Use a randomly generated hash instead.

Comment: @John Still returning undefined. My Node server operates at same localhost but different port.

Comment: Then use the same port in your domain. http://127.0.0.1:123 . Cookies are not sent cross domain. You can use headers for that instead.

Comment: @John My react-server operates at port 3000 and Node server at port 5000. Is that the problem? Both operate at 127.0.0.1 localhost ip address.

Comment: The cookies are only sent when the url port (default 80) is the same as the server's port. So yea, either get them all on the same port or use headers instead of cookies. Edit: you also need to do the credentials parameter on the login fetch request. Hopefully that will help.